# Does logical contradicton betrays OOP in class design?

Tags: c++, oop

I have 3 classes. They have all similar integers,  methods etc...

```
class Country{

      int a,b;
public:
      Country();
      void doSomething();
      :
      :
}

class Military : public Country {
public:
      Power();
      void doAnother();
      void doAnother2();
      :
      :
}

class Technology : public Military{
public:
      Technology();
      void doAnother3();
      :
      :
}
```

Assume that this inheritance suits my solution. But as you see, when i create Military from Country, there is not a relation between them logically. I mean, military is not a country. Also for Technology from country, the problem is same. Technology is not a Military nor Country.

Anyway, that solution is okay for me, it shortens my code, but if i do this, do i betray Object Oriented Programming Philosophy? Is it a contradicton?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For your specific `doSomething` (`tax()`? `signTreaty()`?), does it make sense to say `Technology tech; tech.doSomething()`? If not, then this inheritance does not suit your solution.

Comment: FWIW, it looks like you are trying to construct a `Military` with `Power`. While that may be philosophically true, it isn't value C++.

Comment: Yes… not even `typedef Military Power;` will fix that in the view of C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's against OOP. You relationships are `has-a`, not `is-a`.

You should use composition instead of inheritance for this.

```
class Country{
      Military m;  //Country has-a military
      int a,b;
public:
      Country();
      void doSomething();
}

class Military{
      Technology t; //Military has-a technology
public:
      Military();
      void doAnother();
      void doAnother2();
}

class Technology{
public:
      Technology();
      void doAnother3();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

All of these inheritance relationships are false. A country "has a" military, and a military "has" technology. Therefore they should be members. Inheritance is for "is a" relationships.

If you subvert the intended meaning of language constructs, you will probably pay for it later.

Answer (score 1):

It is a wrong design
When you are inheriting some class its an `is-a` relationship. and inheritance is not [`code reuse`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/smalltalk.html)

You can establish an `has-a` relationship for the behaviors that are common with them.

such as a keyboard has buttons, also my shirt has. but my shirt `is not a` keyboard.
so It should be designed as `shirt has buttons` and `keyboards has buttons` too.